# Multiple NPM errors while trying to install dependecies

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm working with React, with windows 10 , NPM - 2.15.12, Node v6.11.3 .
While trying to install dependencies with Create-React-App - i get the following errors :

```
        C:\xampp\htdocs\react-new-repo>npm i
        npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
        npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\roy\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i"
        npm ERR! node v6.11.3
        npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
        npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

        npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@16.2.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
        npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-dom@16.2.0 wants react@^16.0.0
        npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-router-dom@4.0.0 wants react@^15
        npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-intl-tel-input@4.3.0 wants react@^15.4.2

        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
        npm ERR!     C:\xampp\htdocs\react-new-repo\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you can not use react v16 with your project as it has dependencies that require v15.

You can either specify v15 for react in your `package.json` i.e.

```
"dependencies": {
   "react": "15.6.2"
   ...
```

Or you can try upgrading the dependencies (i.e. `react-router-dom` and `react-intl-tel-input`) to versions that work with react v16

Comment: Thanks, i actually reinstall node - but it did helped for another problem.